# Current date inside single quotes in java

Tags: java, oracle

```
static SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd- MMM-yyyy");
static String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());

private static final String SELECT_BY_AUDIT_KEY_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM 
     t02 WHERE t02_create_date = " + date;
```

This outputs as :

```
SELECT * FROM t02_transaction_log WHERE t02_create_date = 03-Jul-2018
```

What i want is this :

```
SELECT * FROM t02_transaction_log WHERE t02_create_date = '03-Jul-2018'
```

How can i achieve this get the date in between single quotes?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 5):

You should be using a prepared statement here:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM t02 WHERE t02_create_date = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setDate(1, new Date());
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    // process result set
}
```

While statements are important for preventing things like SQL injection, they are equally useful because they free you from having to worry about formatting details in your query.  In the query string above, we just represent the date by a `?` placeholder, and let the driver handle marshaling the current date into the correct format to be sent to Oracle.

Comment: If date format is differ in database then what happen? Assume t02_create_date is like yyyy-mm-dd format in this case how your prepare statement will work?

Comment: @Gaj That doesn't matter, because each database vendor provides a JDBC driver which "knows" what the correct date format going out to the database should be.  So, the answer to your question is, we don't know (or really care), because the driver handles this.

Comment: `setTimestamp` maybe as Gaj probably hints at time info HH:mm:ss being zeroed `by java.sql.Date`.

Comment: I don't think JDBC will take care of this. As per me, Date object will return ISO date format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS).  My question is if the create_date is stored in different format with or without timestamp then what happen?

Comment: I'm not sure I see the concern here.  The OP seems to be wanting to compare against a date, not a timestamp.

Comment: @Gaj the column in the database should be a DATE. It seems you're thinking of it being a VARCHAR or something. If that is the case, your table was created *wrong*.

Comment: Agree that you should use a prepared statement. Provided that you are using at least Java 8 and at least JDBC 4.2 you should also not use `Date` but the modern `LocalDate` and then `ps.setObject(1, LocalDate.now(yourTimeZone));` (time zone is necessary given that it is never the same day everywhere on the globe and we want to control “which today” it’s taking).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

> get the date in between single quotes?

**Don’t.** You should be using smart objects, not dumb strings, to exchange date values with your database.

Use *java.time* classes that replaced troublesome legacy classes.

For date-only values, use `LocalDate` class that replaced `java.sql.Date`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 
    … , 
    LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) 
)
```

…and retrieval…

```
myResultSet.getObject( 
    … ,
    LocalDate.class 
)
```

## java.time

The [Answer by Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51152661/642706) is correct, but uses troublesome old classes. The `java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and related old date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

As of JDBC 4.2 and later, we can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database. Use [`PreparedStatement::setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject(int,java.lang.Object)) and [`ResultSet::getObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject(int,java.lang.Class)) methods.

### Date-only

If your database column is of a date-only type without time-of-day and without time zone, akin to the SQL-standard `DATE` type, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class. Example code:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;  // 2018-01-23.
String sql = "SELECT * FROM t02 WHERE t02_create_date = ? ;" ;  // Tip: Make a habit of closing your SQL properly with a semicolon. Won't hurt, and might help.
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
ps.setObject( 1 , localDate );
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    LocalDate ld = rs.getObject( 1 , LocalDate.class ) ;  // Retrieve an `LocalDate` class.
}
```

### Date-time

If your database column is of a date-with-time-of-day type, akin to the SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` type, use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class. Example code:

```
LocalDate instant = LocalDate.of( 
String sql = "SELECT * FROM t02 WHERE t02_create_date = ? ;" ;  // Tip: Make a habit of closing your SQL properly with a semicolon. Won't hurt, and might help.
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
ps.setObject( 1 , instant );
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    Instant instantRetrieved = rs.getObject( 1 , Instant.class ) ;  // Retrieve an `Instant` class.
    // You may want to adjust from UTC to some other time zone.
    ZoneID z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
    ZonedDateTime zdt = instantRetrieved.atZone( z ) ;  // Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time as seen by the people of some particular region (a time zone). 
}
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 private static final String SELECT_BY_AUDIT_KEY_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM 
     t02 WHERE t02_create_date = to_date('" + date + "', 'dd-mon-yyyy')";
```

Comment: Downvoted because best practice here is to use a prepared statement.

Comment: I found a solution      private static final String SELECT_BY_AUDIT_KEY_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM t02 WHERE t02_create_date ="+ "\'"+ date + "\'";

Comment: @vjanu Please don't do that. Just use a proper PreparedStatement.